# Вычислить координаты точки на увеличенном объекте

Tags: алгоритм, геометрия, координаты, zoom

[image: Смещение координат точки]

Допустим есть прямоугольник, внутри которого на определённых координатах находится точка.
При увеличении размеров прямоугольника координаты точки смещаются.
Нужен алгоритм вычисления этих координат.

Comment: По какому закону "увеличиваются размеры прямоугольника" и по какому закону "координаты точки смещаются"?

Answer (score 2):

непонятно в чём сложность

если известны исходные координаты точки а также размеры прямоугольника то новые координаты точки можно будет получить по такой формуле:

```
xNew = x * xScale
yNew = y * yScale
```

где

```
xScale = (w + a) / w
yScale = (h + b) / h
```

`w` - ширина, `h` - высота,

`a` - приращение по ширине, `b` - приращение по высоте

по сути это простое аффинное преобразование на плоскости